# Adding custom links to Dailymotion embed

Tags: javascript

include js file "swfobject.js"
js code is as follows:

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "mydmplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/VIDEO_ID&enablejsapi=1&
playerapiid=dmplayer", 
"dmapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

I am using this code to embed video into my html. Now I want to create custom links like "play", "fast forward" etc.

Could you please guide me, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function play()
{
mydmplayer.playVideo();
}
</script>
<a onclick="play();" >Play</a>
```

it will play the video if paused. you have to use api parameters to start video automatically. play != start.